# Mono VB .Net application, missing System.Collections.Generic Mac OS X

Tags: vb.net, macos, mono

I'm in the process of porting over a Windows VB .Net 2.0 project over to Mac OS X and i am using Mono to make the process much easier, all of my lib files came across ok, except I cannot add the reference System.Collections.Generic namespace. I require this name space for Dictionary and Specialized.NameValueCollection.

Is this a limitation of Mac OS X or is there a way around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, full namespaces don't match up to assemblies in most cases. `System.Collections.Generic` is a namespace, but the classes within that namespace are defined in assemblies `mscorlib.dll` and `System.dll` (excluding other classes like `SynchronizedCollection<T>`, which exists in `System.ServiceModel.dll`).

Make sure you are referencing `mscorlib` and `System` and you should be fine.

Comment: Inside Monodevelop for Mac OS X, how would I do this? I know how to do it in VB, but not Mono :P, I have System added, but not sure how to add mscorlib, it's not in the list

Comment: Per [Mono's documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Need_Help), `mscorlib.dll` and `System.dll` are referenced by default.